# Is it possible to pass data between custom service worker and React components?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have a create-react-app and I created a custom service worker in public folder. In the src I have the default serviceWorker.js file. In the public folder in the custom service worker file I added a push event listener like this:

```
 self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {

  const someData= event.data.text();
  const title = "Test";
  const options = {
    body: someData,
    icon: "./someIcon.png",
    badge: "./someIcon.png",
  };
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

The thing is that before I show this notification I need to apply some transformation to the data I receive from the event and for that I need this data in some react component, do the transformation there and then do this: `event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));`
with the transformation applied to my data so the user gets that data as notification eventually. Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible to accomplish that, because you don't have any way of knowing whether there will be a web page open for your origin when the `push` event handler is invoked. Your service worker might be woken up at any point in time with a `push` event received from your push notification server, and there's no guarantee that your web app will also be open.

Because of this, I'd try not to go down the road of implementing something that used `postMessage()` to conditionally talk between the service worker and the client page (if it is open), since that's code that would only work some of the time.

Instead, you should implement all the code that you need in order to display the notification inside of the service worker itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I have to modify data on the server side and send it already modified since it doesn't work like that on front-end side.